# Скачать несколько файлов одним кликом

Tags: javascript, jquery, websocket

нужен скрипт, который скачивает файлы с сервера и сохраняет в локальной папке.

файлов очень много, около 2000 файлов.

Думал написать java websocket  и подключиться с javascipt, отправить файлы, и java  будет сохранят файлы.

есть другие идеи?

Answer (score 2):

Это очень плохая идея, т.к. javascript не даст тебе этого сделать. Лучше написать отдельно программу на Java/C/C++/другое, которая скачает эти 2000 файлов и сохранит их в отдельную папку. Опиши задачу подробнее, может что-нибудь подскажу.

Comment: у меня в базе есть данные, oracle 11g, теперь в отчетах клиент должен иметь возможность скачать данные в формате xml, каждый в отдельном файле, и в определенный папку, C:\\EXCHANGE\IN.

Comment: Я не работал под oracle 11g, я полагаю, это база данных, значит 99.9%, что к ней можно подключиться с клиента, sql запросами достать информацию и записать на в нужном виде. Конкретного кода тебе привести не смогу.